# Can I use micronaut-serde-jackson + declarative http client + lombok?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-serde

I am attempting to use micronaut-serde-jackson with a declarative HTTP client to make a simple GET request and retrieve a deserialized POJO.

The POJO looks like this (I'm using lombok):

```java
@Data
@Serdeable
public class Thing {
    private String color;
}
```

The client looks like this:

```java
@Client("http://endpoint/api")
@Header(name = ACCEPT, value = "application/json")
public interface ThingClient {
    @SingleResult
    @Get("/things/{id}")
    Thing resolve(@PathVariable String id);
}
```

I call the client as follows:

```java
   Thing thing = thingClient.resolve("id123");
```

The request is successful. Server returns 200 OK, the response json is correct, and a Thing instance is returned, but its `color` field is null. No errors are logged.

Edit:

It seems that lombok code generation doesn't occur before micronaut's, and serde seems to need getters/setters to exist in order to bind values from the JSON payload, so I end up with no fields being filled.

I'm using Maven and IntelliJ and lombok's annotation processor is defined first in both tools. Not sure why this isn't working; I'll keep poking at it and post back if I find a solution.

Comment: Some of the information at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/218 may be helpful.

Comment: I looked over the issue, and the solution discussed amounted to setting up lombok's annotation processor before Micronaut's, which I had already done. In my setup, lombokized beans work fine in micronaut - but not in serde object mapping.